# Class Button needs Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I have a class named Button.It holds 4 variables : x,y,width,height.In my program i have many buttons and for each button i would need a diferent function.Something like a vector of pointers to functions.I have no idea how to do that.Please guide me.

Comment: What you need is an event system. This is implemented in different ways in different UI frameworks. Are you writing a framework?

Comment: No.I dont know what that is.I use sfml to draw things on my screen.The Button class uses sfml to draw a rectangle on my screen.

Comment: Yes.For each button i need a diferent function

Comment: Why not just have a member function that does what you need? Inherit from "Button" and let the member function deal with whatever it needs to do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are writing this code for educational purposes. If not (=if this is intended to be used in some production system) then my advice would be to use some framework that will provide all this low level stuff (say Qt for example).

Instead of using function-pointers, wich is kind of an "old school" technique, I would suggest adding a [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to your class, and initialising with the function you want to be called.

For example, something like this:

```
class Button
{
   private:
      int x,y,width,height;
      std::function<void()> Callback;
   public:
      Button( std::function<void()> f ) : Callback(f) {}
};
```

Comment: Yes its for educational purposes.What my program needs is for me to not have do declare x functions like this : void f1(); void f2(); ... Instead i want somehow to have all f functions stored in somekind of vector and to declare them as such: void f[1]() ,void f[2]()....

Comment: I edited answer, it's better to store the callback inside the class, instead of having to maintain an external vector of functions. Although that could be possible too.